# Re-test after review ban to lift ban

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, review-suspension

I've just been dinged for having too many incorrect reviews.
While the punitive action seems strange, I do get the point of it.

As an alternative, would it be possible to offer a re-test: e.g., 5 audit reviews correctly reviewed gets you unbanned. This may improve the review quality and act as a training exercise to prevent future infractions.

I don't think banning genuinely concerned users really helps anyone, especially if you're looking for more (quality) engagement and not less.

And thoughts or comments?

Comment: Audits are _hard_ to get wrong. You actively have to not pay attention. You said "No action needed" on [this obvious "Me too!" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9105735). If that is any indication for your review record, I'd say the ban is spot-on. If the system would let you "try again", the only benefit would be that you learn how to game the system.

Comment: The current audit system is extremely trivial to beat and is literally only designed to catch people who click the review buttons without even looking at the post. Using correct audits as a metric for unbanning wouldn't make sense as such a system would be extremely easy to game.

Comment: @CodeCaster I read each post, and answer as I think is appropriate. Seems sadly cynical to think a person would attempt to game the system. You can see my review history and that I'm attempting to contribute.

Comment: The reality is that many try to game the system - and the system can not distinguish between a so called 'genuine' user and a mostly successful robo-reviewer

Comment: @Mort the sad reality is that the majority of reviewers only review for the gamification of it. They don't (seem to) care about quality, they just want those badges - hence the term robo-reviewers you'll find often used on Meta. From your last ten reviews it seems you click _"Looks OK"_  / _"No action needed"_ way too easily. Pay more attention to the post you're reviewing.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for the update. Will do. Must be a difficult balancing act between trying to encourage users to participate and prevent the gamification.

Comment: @Mort If there was never anyone reviewing inappropriately (which seems to be your premise) then there would be no need for audits at all.  They were created precisely because there *is* a need for them; the abuse of the review system before they were added was so bad that the entire review system was causing major harm to the site because the vast majority of reviewers were abusing it, rather than actually reviewing posts.

Comment: @Servyit is not my premise at all that there are never inappropriate reviews. It was merely a point of discussion, i.e. could there be a false positive in the ban, and could there be a different option in dealing with the ban. E.g. if I review 200 items "correctly", and fail 5, have I done more good or damage to the site and community? I've done incorrect reviews (clearly) but as a result of not being sure, or thinking it was right. The intent was correct, the execution flawed. Again, not disputing the ban, just discussing options. Thanks for your reply..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that's a good idea. SO wants you to pay attention all the time. Not after a certain number of failed audits, just to get you back to reviewing again. The first failed audit should have been a lesson. When it apparently wasn't, you're just going to have to sit this one out for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Statistically, do you find users who've been banned become better reviewers, or just stop reviewing?

Comment: I personally couldn't tell you because I don't have the statistics. But I'm sure those who have will weigh in.

Comment: @Mort can't tell stats, but FWIW here's an isolated anecdote. I've been suspended from suggesting edits few years ago. Now I have 5 or 6 gold badges for editing and am top editor at 3 or 4 (maybe 5) sites. Yes, that old suspension made me think more of how to improve posts I edit

Comment: Thanks @gnat. This ban certainly won't prevent me answering other questions, or arrest my reviewing in future. I was more just proposing a possible option for discussion, which has been pretty comprehensively answered above! :)

Comment: A small additional comment for anyone else reading this: when in doubt, don't try and answer the review as best as possible, just click Skip (as per SO's instructions).